# cp command from tcl script

Tags: linux, tcl

Hi I am writing a tcl script to automate the task in linux. In that I want to copy files. 
The command is 
`cp -r source destination`. I have tried using 
`puts [cp -rf source destination]`. But I am getting error saying invalid command cp. How will I write it in tcl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run an external program from your script, you should use the `exec` command:

```
puts [exec cp -r $source $destination]
```

However, for the specific case of copying a directory from one place to another you can use the built-in [`file copy`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M10) command (which works with directories as well as files):

```
file copy $source $destination
```